# Support for compiling ASN1 file to C with CONTAINING keyword

Tags: c, asn.1

I'm using ESNACC for compiling multiple ASN source files to C code. For ease of understanding, I will explain the scenario here as succintly as possible:-

FileA.asn1 contains the following:-

```
FileA DEFINITIONS ::= 
BEGIN
  A ::= SEQUENCE       
  {  
        AContent   [0] OCTET STRING (CONTAINING FileB.B) 
  }                                                     
END
```

FileB.asn1 contains the following:-

```
FileB DEFINITIONS ::= 
BEGIN
  B ::= SEQUENCE       
  {  
        BElem1   [0]  INTEGER,
        BElem2   [1]  INTEGER
  }                                                     
END
```

I used ESNACC to compile both files in one command. Upon analysing the C source files generated, I observed that the `AContent` field will be decoded as a constructed `OCTET STRING` (the data being received in the application guarantees that the field will be specified as constructed) with its contents being filled into a simple string. This means that `FileB` does not come into the picture at all. I was hoping that `AContent` would be further decoded with a structure of `FileB` being filled, so that I can easily access the elements within. This does not seem to be the case.

I'm fairly new with ASN1, so please let me know if my understanding is wrong in any way.

1. Is ESNACC not capable of generating code for supporting `CONTAINING` keyword properly?
2. Are there other compilers that are able to do this?
3. Can this be done by using ESNACC in any way?
4. If this cannot be done using ESNACC, and I don't want to use any other compiler, how would I access the contents within `AContent` at runtime easily?

Comment: The source code for the compiler seems to imply that CONTAINING is handled: https://github.com/esnacc/esnacc-ng/blob/master/compiler/core/y.tab.y#L1633

Comment: Actually older versions of the compiler threw a parsing error at CONTAINING keyword. This change was added in later versions. Now, it doesn't throw a parsing error, but I can see no difference in the code generated if I use the CONTAINING clause vs if I don't use it at all.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of the capabilities of ESNACC, but there are many other compilers that support the CONTAINING keyword.  An excellent list of compilers can be found at https://www.itu.int/en/ITU-T/asn1/Pages/Tools.aspx which is part of the ITU-T ASN.1 Project.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I'm working on a legacy project, and switching compilers might mean a large number of changes throughout the project which I'm trying to avoid. If I use ESNACC, it gives me the ```OCTET STRING``` of ```AContent```. Can I then use a decoding function of ```FileB``` to further decode this ```OCTET STRING``` into B's structure? Is this the correct line of thinking?

Comment: @Nikhil Yes, that would be the approach to take if your compiler doesn't provide more helpful support.  Also, look at the documentation for your compiler.  There might be something for turning support for it on/off.

Comment: Thank you Paul Thorpe, I'd not come across that list of tools before - very useful! I was already familiar with a few of them, but there are whole new-to-me ones to explore :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Heimdal](https://github.com/heimdal/heimdal)'s ASN.1 compiler (`lib/asn1/`) has support for the funky Information Object System syntax extensions that allow you to declare things like what all goes into `Certificate` `Extensions` (for example), and the generated code will decode everything recursively in one go.